# animation playing on emulator and not on device windows phone 8.1

Tags: windows-runtime, windows-phone-8.1, winrt-xaml, emulation

I am developing an application and trying to achieve a sort of flip effect(like flipboard)

this is my xaml.

```
<Page.Resources>
    <Storyboard x:Name="FlipBottomStoryboard">
        <DoubleAnimation Duration="0:0:1.1" To="-80.9" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Projection).(PlaneProjection.RotationX)" Storyboard.TargetName="grid" d:IsOptimized="True"/>
    </Storyboard>
</Page.Resources>
<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="2*"/>
        <RowDefinition/>
        <RowDefinition/>
        <RowDefinition Height="2*"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Grid Grid.RowSpan="2">
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="2*"/>
            <RowDefinition/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Rectangle Stroke="Black" Fill="#FF4E608F"/>
    </Grid>
    <Grid x:Name="grid" Grid.Row="2" Grid.RowSpan="2" Canvas.ZIndex="1">
        <Grid.Projection>
            <PlaneProjection CenterOfRotationX="0" CenterOfRotationY="0"/>
        </Grid.Projection>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition/>
            <RowDefinition Height="2*"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Interactivity:Interaction.Behaviors>
            <Core:EventTriggerBehavior EventName="Tapped">
                <Media:ControlStoryboardAction Storyboard="{StaticResource FlipBottomStoryboard}"/>
            </Core:EventTriggerBehavior>
        </Interactivity:Interaction.Behaviors>
        <Rectangle Fill="#FF3DDA24" Stroke="Black" Grid.Row="1"/>
    </Grid>
    <Rectangle Stroke="Black" Grid.Row="1" Grid.RowSpan="2">
        <Rectangle.Fill>
            <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="0.5,1" StartPoint="0.5,0">
                <GradientStop Color="Black" Offset="0"/>
                <GradientStop Color="#FFA65757"/>
                <GradientStop Color="#FF0A2E26" Offset="0.966"/>
            </LinearGradientBrush>
        </Rectangle.Fill>
    </Rectangle>

</Grid>
```

In short the grid on the lower half animates its RotationX when it is tapped. 
The problem is that on the emulator(WVGA 4 inch 512mb) this works well but on the device (lumia 630 512mb) the animation jumps from the initial position to the end. Also the framerate drops to 30.

Any help is welcome on the matter

Comment: Did you tried replacing gradient with just regular color?

Comment: @Festyk No I didn't why do you think it would be useful? In any case the part with the gradient color does not animate. The part below it does.

Comment: Maybe some rendering issues? I came up with another idea: You can add CacheMode = "BitmapCache" to the animating grid.

Comment: @Festyk tried that too. Didn't work :( Thanks though

Comment: I may have some interesting info for you. I tested your piece of code on my lumia 820 and it works fine, without any lags.

Comment: @Festyk Thanks again. I suppose it has to do with low end devices being unable to handle the animation.